# Sharepoint Alert Access denied

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been working on a interface to add list alerts for the current user on Sharepoint 2010. With high privilege users I can add and remove the alerts from lists and documents, but when I'm using a low level user "Visitor" with **Read permissions** on the site and list/document I can't add multiple alerts or remove them. It's one by one, and I get a "Access Denied".

If you want I can show you my code.
TIA.

Comment: Is it an option to just privilege escalate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're not sandboxed, can you use a delegate to run with elevated permissions?  e.g.

```
string employeeIdToRemove = "1337";
Guid siteGuid = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPermissions(delegate
{
   using (SPSite mySite = new SPSite(siteGuid))
   {
      SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists["SuperSecretList"].Items;
      int itemCount = listItems.Count;

      for (int k=0; k<itemCount; k++)
      {
         SPListItem item = listItems[k];

         if (employeeIdToRemove.Equals(item["Employee"].ToString()))
         {
             listItems.Delete(k);
         }
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: hey, I've already tried that, and yes I'm not sandboxed forgot to mention that... but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: You're doing that but you're still getting access denied?